# is there an afterEach for modules in angular unit tests?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test a switch statement where config is a constant injected into the controller

```
vm.twoFaSecondaryMethod = config[countryCode].twoFaSecondaryMethod;

switch (vm.twoFaSecondaryMethod) {
    case 'CARDLAST4DIGIT':
        vm.twoFaSecondaryMethodInfo = translate.get('verifyOneTimePassword.cardVerificationSubHeading');
        vm.twoFaSecondaryMethodErrorText = translate.get('verifyOneTimePassword.cardVerificationError');
        break;
    case 'NATIONALID':
        vm.twoFaSecondaryMethodInfo = translate.get('verifyOneTimePassword.nationalIDSubHeading');
        vm.twoFaSecondaryMethodErrorText = translate.get('verifyOneTimePassword.nationalIDError');
        break;
    case 'POSTALCODE':
        vm.twoFaSecondaryMethodInfo = translate.get('verifyOneTimePassword.postalCodeSubHeading');
        vm.twoFaSecondaryMethodErrorText = translate.get('verifyOneTimePassword.postalCodeError');
        break;
    case 'CARDEXPIRYDATE':
        vm.twoFaSecondaryMethodInfo = translate.get('verifyOneTimePassword.cardExpirySubHeading');
        vm.twoFaSecondaryMethodErrorText = translate.get('verifyOneTimePassword.cardExpiryError');
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

I've been able to test the first branch 'CARDLAST4DIGIT' with this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    bard.appModule('verifyOneTimePassword', function($provide) {
        $provide.value('localeService', {
            getCountry: function() {
                return 'US';
            }
        });

        $provide.constant('config', {
            us: {
                twoFaSecondaryMethod: 'CARDLAST4DIGIT',
                twoFaPrimaryMethod: 'SMS',
                phonePrefix: 'US+1'
            }
        });
    });
```

Unfortunately this beforeEach with the provides is necessary to get my main beforeEach to even run,... is there anyway I reinitialize the module with a modified provider say

```
bard.appModule('verifyOneTimePassword', function($provide) {
    $provide.value('localeService', {
        getCountry: function() {
            return 'US';
        }
    });

    $provide.constant('config', {
        us: {
            twoFaSecondaryMethod: 'NATIONALID',
            twoFaPrimaryMethod: 'SMS',
            phonePrefix: 'US+1'
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah there is a `afterEach` you can use it like:

```js
describe("A spec (with setup and tear-down)", function() {
    var foo;

    beforeEach(function() {
      foo = 0;
      foo += 1;
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      foo = 0;
    });

    it("is just a function, so it can contain any code", function() {
      expect(foo).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

[Here is the Jasmine specification](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html)